# Boost ASIO Threading Performance Issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, performance, caching, boost-asio

I'm working under ubuntu with gcc 4.7. I'm trying to make a networking library to send data over udp.

I am using a boost::asio::io_service with a number of threads calling io_service::run() to set up a thread pool. I am using async_receive_from to wait for data without blocking a thread. Once some data is read a new async_read is started and the received data is passed up my stack by the thread that received it. I am creating a separate stack for each address I have received data from and using a tbb::concurrent_hash_map to lock each stack while a message is being passed up it. You can see the relevant piece of code below.

Now for my problem, when I run with just 1 thread in my thread pool I receive most of the packets, but when I run with 2 threads in the pool I drop a lot more packets. From this I'm reading threading issue, but I can't work out exactly what my issue is. Nothing shows up in my profiler (valgrind --tool=callgrind). Does anyone have any ideas?

```
public :    
    /* Virtual functions for sending and receiving messages */
    virtual void received(const boost::asio::ip::address &addr, msg_data *const data, const msg_header *const header) override
    {
        /* Pend the next read */
        start_receiving();

        /* Check if there exists a parallel stack for this address, if not create it */
        typename stack_map::accessor stack_acc;
        if (_strands.insert(stack_acc, addr.to_string()))
        {
            std::cout << "cloning stack: " << addr.to_string() << std::endl;
            stack_acc->second = this->_up_node->clean_clone();
        }

        /* While holding the lock on this stack, propagate the message */
        stack_acc->second->received(addr, data, header);
    }

    /* Start waiting for data on the socket */
    virtual void start_receiving() override
    {
        /* Prepare receive buffer */
        char *data_buf = new char [MAX_UDP_SIZE];
        std::array<boost::asio::mutable_buffer, 2> recv_buf =
        {{
            boost::asio::buffer(_head_buf, HEADER_SIZE),
            boost::asio::buffer(data_buf, MAX_UDP_SIZE)
        }};

        /* Wait for data */
        _recv_socket.async_receive_from(recv_buf, _recv_endpoint,
            [&,data_buf](const boost::system::error_code &, size_t bytes_transferred)
            {
                received(_recv_endpoint.address(), new msg_data(data_buf, bytes_transferred - HEADER_SIZE), new msg_header(_head_buf));
            });
    }
private :
    typedef tbb::concurrent_hash_map<std::string, stack_component*> stack_map;
    stack_map _strands;
```

**EDIT:**
So I rewrote my code to the below and it performance wasn't affected by the number of threads anymore. I'm guessing the problem was related to synchronising data across multiple processor caches, but I don’t have any evidence. Does anyone have a better guess or some way I can gather evidence (preferably a free way :) )?

```
    /* Start waiting for data on the socket */
    virtual void start_receiving() override
    {
        while (true)
        {
            /* Prepare receive buffer */
            char *data_buf = new char [MAX_UDP_SIZE];
            char *head_buf = new char [HEADER_SIZE];
            std::array<boost::asio::mutable_buffer, 2> recv_buf =
            {{
                boost::asio::buffer(head_buf, HEADER_SIZE),
                boost::asio::buffer(data_buf, MAX_UDP_SIZE)
            }};

            /* Wait for data */
            size_t bytes_transferred = _recv_socket.receive_from(recv_buf, _recv_endpoint);

            _io_service.post([&,head_buf,data_buf,bytes_transferred]()
                {
                    msg_header *header = new msg_header(head_buf);
                    delete [] head_buf;
                    received(_recv_endpoint.address(), new msg_data(data_buf, bytes_transferred - HEADER_SIZE), header);
                });
        }
    }

    /* Virtual functions for sending and receiving messages */
    virtual void received(const boost::asio::ip::address &addr, msg_data *const data, const msg_header *const header) override
    {
        /* Check if there exists a parallel stack for this address, if not create it */
        typename stack_map::accessor stack_acc;
        if (_strands.insert(stack_acc, addr.to_string()))
        {
            stack_acc->second = this->_up_node->clean_clone();
        }

        /* While holding the lock on this stack, propagate the message */
        stack_acc->second->received(addr, data, header);
    }
```